# Basic JAVA variable reach from different files

Tags: java, class, variables

I have this code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class pruebaframe extends JFrame
{
       public static String elurl="wut";
       JPanel jp = new JPanel();
       JLabel jl = new JLabel();
       JTextField jt = new JTextField(50);
       JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");

       public pruebaframe()
       {
              setTitle("Inserte el URL");
              setVisible(true);
              setSize(600, 200);
              setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              jp.add(jt);


              jp.add(jb);

              jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
              {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                      {
                             String input = jt.getText();
                             elurl=input;
                             jl.setText(input);
                      }
              });


              jp.add(jl);
              add(jp);

       }

    public static String getElurl() {
        return elurl;
    }

    public static void setElurl(String elurl) {
        pruebaframe.elurl = elurl;
    }


}
```

Now i want to use the elurl variable in another class like this:

```
 String url1;
 pruebaframe t = new pruebaframe();
url1 = t.getElurl();
```

so everytime i type something on the Jtextfield url1 changes it values. The thing is its not working. It does not change the value. I know it's a simple problem i just cant find where am i wrong.

Comment: Because they are not the same object that you are working on. New keyword will create other instance, what you need is to control the number of instances that you create.

Comment: But im creating just 1 "pruebaframe" . In another file but still.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but since `elurl` is static, there should only be one value around all the time. Is there even a reason to make `elurl` static? (Though it being static is probably not the reason the value does not update) Also, where do you call `setElurl`? Obviously, the value of `elurl` won't change if you never set it. Are you looking for an event-listener that listens to modifications of the textfield?

Comment: I got rid of the static attribute. Still nothing. I use the setElurl right after the user presses the button. To asign whatever he introduced on the textfield into elurl variable

Comment: So you should probably start debugging where `elurl` is supposed to be assigned. Put a breakpoint there (or a `System.out.println`-statement): If there is no reaction, the code is not called. Otherwise, you're not accessing the value correctly. Note that the `ActionListener` is called asynchronously, so, as **Salih Erikci** already mentioned in his answer, if you cache the value of `elurl` in `url1` **before** the `ActionListener` is triggered, you will still work on the cached value and not see the update.

Comment: This is due to pass by copy-of-reference.  Setting `a` to `b`, then changing `a` does not change `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `peuebaframe` object when action performed. Either by using constructor or method of another class. Then you can get updated value of your jTextField.

*AnotherClass.java*

```
public class AnotherClass {

    private pruebaframe t;

    public AnotherClass(pruebaframe t) {
        this.t= t;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Printing From Another Class: " + t.getElurl());
    }
}
```

And do follwoing.

```
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input = jt.getText();
            elurl = input;
            jl.setText(input);
            AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(pruebaframe.this);
            anotherClass.print();
        }
    });
```

*Output:*

```
Printing From Another Class: <your updated jTextValue>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button after changing the text in `JTextField` a new `String` object is assigned to `elurl`. If you want `url1` to change everytime you should update it too.

Instead of assigning to a variable, call `t.getElurl();`everytime you need the `elurl` value. With this you will always get the latest value of `elurl`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. Since url1 is a variable in another file

Comment: See suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Just did it and still nothing :l

Answer (score 0):

You **static** variable usages should be

```
String url1;
url1 = Pruebaframe.elurl;
```

But I do not recommend to use static variable to pass a parameter because of concurrent issue.